# SCons Regexp Instead of Glob?

Tags: python, regex, filesystems, scons

Is there an SCons function the provides the functionality of Glob, but using Regular Expressions instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get all the entries in a directory, and then filter those by regular expression:

```
import os
import re

print([x for x in os.listdir(".") if re.match(r"[a-z]+[0-9]+", x)])
```

Comment: Which of course could be packaged into a nice function which returns a list of file nodes. Any chance that's already been done, or should I do it and submit it as a patch?

Comment: Not sure whether SCons has that built in already. Since SCons scripts are Python, I usually end up using the facilities of Python itself if I need to do things like that.

Comment: Alright. If no one comes up with an existing function in Python in the next day or so I'll mark your answer as correct, and when I get a chance I'll try to submit a patch to SCons. It's a common enough thing that there should be a function for it.